# How to plot whiskers plot (remove box part in box-whisker plot)

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to visualize confidence intervals e.g. [-1, 1] for an A/B testing result to compare 2 experimental groups visually in Python, the whisker plot withno box with mean point at the center seems a good option, is there a straightforward way to remove the box part from the box-whisker-plot (seaborn pkg) in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a built-in argument for this, pass in `showbox=False` in the `sns.boxplot()` function

```
sns.boxplot(data, showbox=False)
```

Comment: Indeed, see here https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html